# Need to compare a portion of one list with another and see if they have the same numeric order and if not see the elements that are in other position

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to compare one list `lst` with another one `lst2` and see if the values in one `lst` correspond to a portion of the other list `lst2` and if it has the same string order of the first one `lst` and if is not returns the values that do not have the right position.

This are the examples:

```
  lst = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'e']


  lst2 = ['DD', 'OO', 'CC' ,'WW', 'GG', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'AA' 'QQ', 'EE', 'ZZ', 'XX', 'YY', 'UU', 'II', 'OO', 'HH']
```

Supose that the the `lst` values will change. I mean it will have a different `length` with other string values added in near future but the string index `'GG'` and `'AA'` in `lst2` will not change, it just will change the values from `'a'` to `'e'` as `lst` but the process it will be the same.

It is better using pandas dataframes or "\n".join() as string columns or just using list?

Answer (score 0):

The question was not actually clear, but as I understand it - you want to find the elements in `lst2` that did not appear in `lst1`.

for both upcoming approaches I checked with the example inputs as you provided:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'e']
lst2 = ['DD', 'OO', 'CC' ,'WW', 'GG', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'AA' 'QQ', 'EE', 'ZZ', 'XX', 'YY', 'UU', 'II', 'OO', 'HH']
```

If the order of appearances must be the same in both lists - you can use tricky way of manipulating `strings`. like in here:

```
lst_str = ' '.join(lst)
lst2_str = ' '.join(lst2)
index_found = lst2_str.find(lst_str)
lst4 = lst2_str.split()
if index_found!=-1:
    lst4 = (lst2_str[0:index_found] + lst2_str[index_found+len(lst_str):]).split()
```

output:

```
['DD', 'OO', 'CC', 'WW', 'GG', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'AAQQ', 'EE', 'ZZ', 'XX', 'YY', 'UU', 'II', 'OO', 'HH']
```

this approach assume that whitespaces are not allowed in the elements in the lists (you can use other seperator as well of course)

Otherwise if the order does not matter, a simple list comprehension will do the work:

```
lst3 = [item for item in lst2 if not item in lst]
```

output:

```
['DD', 'OO', 'CC', 'WW', 'GG', 'AAQQ', 'EE', 'ZZ', 'XX', 'YY', 'UU', 'II', 'OO', 'HH']
```

the differences between the approaches outputs comes up because the order in elements in `lst` is differet than in `lst2`, therefore the 2 approaches retrieve different outputs

Comment: Thank you for your answer @YossiLevi. Actually I want to get just the comparation between the variables that appear in both `lists` and also get the variables that not are in the order of `lst `.

Comment: I don't understand you. what is the meaning of *the comparation between the variables appear in both lists*? and for the second part - is what I wrote answered you?

Comment: I mean that I want the result show if the variables in `lst2` are in order of `lst` (not considering the other variables 'DD', 'AA'. Just 'a', 'b', etc.). First, I want to compare if `lst` appear in `lst2` (Just `'a', 'b',` etc.) and if it is false (because the order values in `lst` are different from `lst2`) I want to know which values do not have the order of `lst` (that in this case are: `'c','d'` because in `lst` is like `'d','c'`).